# Clarification about induced inner product on exterior powers of a vector space.

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm having a bit of trouble understanding the induced inner product on exterior powers of a (real)vector space. For $\Lambda ^k V $, the text I'm following defines it as follows: If $g$ is a metric on $V$, then

$ (v_1 \wedge... \wedge v_k,w_1 \wedge ... \wedge w_k)=\det (g(v_i,w_j))  $.

My gap in understanding is how this is extended to vectors $x,y \in \Lambda^k V$ that are linear combinations of the basis and not decomposable into a single $k$-wedge product. Do you simply insist that $(x,y)$ is the sum of the determinants as given above by expanding $(x,y)$ in the usual way as sums of inner products of their linear combinations?

Comment: Yes, the inner product must be bilinear, i.e. has the usual distributivity property over addition. Is $\dim V=k$? What do you exactly mean by 'metric' $g$? Is it just the given inner product?

Comment: I misspoke, g is meant to be an inner product (for my purposes, eventually a Riemannian metric at some $T_pM$, hence the error). $\dim V=n > k$. I believe the situation becomes rather trivial if $k=\dim V$